Serious extrapolation of oil price futures
I'm looking for sources in the Internet where I can find serious expectations / outlook on oil prices during the next 2 - 15 years.
First I searched for oil futures, because I am an old man and I have learned years ago in school, that futures are contracts to buy or sell a specific underlying asset or commodity at a future date.
I researched a little while in the net, but I didn't find any outlook or futures on oil and only that serious OPEC report here:
https://www.opec.org/opec_web/static_files_project/media/downloads/publications/OPEC_MOMR_January-2024.pdf

My questions:

Are there still mid-term / long-term futures on oil and where are they traded?
Is there a average report about all traded futures, that approximates an oil price in the futures.


You didn’t look very hard.  Oil futures are traded at the CME.  You can see prices out to 2035 at CME group.com.
